# AWS EBCLI setup, virtualenv not found in /home/<user>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/virtualenv

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, virtualenv

I am trying to set up Elastic Beanstalk cli on Ubuntu 20.04, and am following [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup) tutorial.

When I run `./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/bundled_installer`, I get an error saying that it can't find virtualenv in my pyenv version.

```
==============================================
II. Creating self-contained EBCLI installation
==============================================

******************************************
1. Creating exclusive virtualenv for EBCLI
******************************************
/bin/sh: 1: /home/julien/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin/virtualenv: not found
   Exiting due to failure
```

I have tried reinstalling pyenv version 3.7.2, and still no luck. What do I need to do to get this process moving past this point?

Comment: Which ubuntu exactly?

Comment: So sorry, Ubuntu 20.04.2. I have edited my question to include that